# Text in math mode: inherit bold but not italics

Tags: math-mode, bold, italic

Can I define a macro `\foo` so that `$\foo$` produces:

- bold sans-serif "foo", if the surrounding text is bold
- normal sans-serif "foo" otherwise.

In particular, "foo" should never be typeset in *italics*.

MWE that does not quite work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newcommand{\foo}{\textsf{foo}}
\begin{document}
\section{This should be bold: $\foo$, \boldmath$2^\foo$}
This should be normal: $\foo$, $2^\foo$.
\begin{theorem}This should be normal: $\foo$, $2^\foo$.\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Here I get slanted text in the theorem environment; otherwise it looks good. If I try e.g.:

```
\newcommand{\foo}{\textnormal{\textsf{foo}}}
```

then it is always in normal font, not bold.

Can I just somehow "turn off italics" without "turning off bold"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can add one more level to the font specification for `\foo`:

```
\newcommand{\foo}{\textsf{\upshape foo}}
```

`\textup` would also work, but requires the "argument" form, `\textup{foo}`.
both are defined in "basic" latex, so no extra packages are needed.

**edit:** as pointed out by Jukka in a comment, this is the best of all possibilities:

```
\text{\upshape\sffamily foo}
```

it will size correctly if used in sub- or superscripts, and it will avoid a (meaningless)
font warning that is produced by both `\textup` and `\upshape` when used in this manner.

**edit 2:**  Bernard provides a variation for the typing minimalists that works as well:

```
\textup{\sffamily foo}
```

Comment: It seems that this version gives a missing font warning (just like my original MWE). I guess it would be better to first use `\upshape` and only after that `\sffamily` to avoid the warning, e.g., `\text{\upshape\sffamily foo}`?

Comment: @JukkaSuomela -- yes.  thank you for pointing that out. i'll add this to the exposition.

Comment: Or even (less typing) `\textup{\sffamily foo}`?

Comment: @Bernard -- okay.  that works too.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\textsf{\textup{foo}}`. But it looks odd that you are using your command always in math. In this context I would use `\mathsf`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newcommand{\foomath}{\mathsf{foomath}}
\newcommand\foo{\textsf{\textup{foo}}}
\begin{document}
\section{This should be bold: \mathversion{bold}$\foo \foomath$}
This should be normal: $\foo\foomath$.
\begin{theorem}This should be normal: $\foo\foomath$.\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this alternative, even if it does not do exactly what I wanted. :)

Comment: Well it depends on the meaning of `foo`: If it is a "math variable" then it should be set with math font commands. If you want to avoid to have to insert the \mathversion{bold} you can add it to the section definition.

Comment: Is there a painless way to make `\mathsf{foo}` look like `\textsf{foo}` if I am using `\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}`, i.e., Charter as serif font and Helvetica as sans-serif font?

Comment: Sure. `\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathsf}{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet\mathsf{bold}{OT1}{phv}{bx}{n}`

Answer (score 2):

By putting it in an `\mbox` with `\upshape`, it dispenses with the italics.  However, it won't rescale to subscripted math styles and the like, as is.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newcommand{\foo}{\mbox{\upshape\textsf{foo}}}
\begin{document}
\section{This should be bold: $\foo$}
This should be normal: $\foo$.
\begin{theorem}This should be normal: $\foo$. still italic here\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

However, with just a little extra work (and also taking Joseph's suggestion), it can be made to scale with the math size:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,scalerel}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newcommand{\foo}{\scaleto{\mbox{\upshape\sffamily foo}}{1.6\LMex}}
\begin{document}
\section{This should be bold: $\foo$}
This should be normal: $\foo$ and $\foo_{\foo}$.
\begin{theorem}This should be normal: $\foo$. still italic here\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And as Jukka points out in the comment, a simpler definition (requiring `amsmath` but not requiring the `scalerel` package) that also scales with math size is

```
\newcommand{\foo}{\text{\upshape\sffamily foo}}
```

Comment: I'd have gone for `\upshape\sffamily` as there is no real need for an argument-based approach here :-)

Comment: Why not just use `\text` instead of `\mbox`; then it would also scale correctly?